# What does Windows PC do with an overheated HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, cooling, overheating, disk-protection

recently I was frequently getting alarms (via StableBit Scanner) that one of my HDDs is getting over 45°C hot. The system isn't always on.

Yesterday my HDD disappeared from Windows. Even when I shut down, let it cool and started again the HDD was not visible. I've opened the case, removed and reconnected the SATA cable and the HDD was visible again, until it disappeared in 30 Minutes again.

I've moved the HDD to a better position, under a Case fan, now it peaks at 39°C. Since then it's working.

StableBit Scanner says that the HDD is healthy.

Did Windows or the Mainboard shut down the HDD to prevent overheat damage? Can I trust this HDD if I keep it cooler from now on?

Comment: An HDD disappearing from Windows is not a good sign. Back up all important data.

Comment: What's the exact model of the disk?

Comment: It's a 2 TB Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001

Comment: I would imagine the disappearing hdd was not a windows feature but the drive's own behavior during overheating.  The drive likely was no longer communicating with the controller so was removed (like disconnecting a drive).  You can learn more by reviewing the windows event logs from the affected periods.  Can also take a look at the drives smart data.  Most importantly as mentioned by others, back up your data as this behavior is unusual and hdd failure is a risk to consider.